# trying to check if a long integer is prime

Tags: c, math

I'm writing a program to check whether a given integer is prime. My program works for integers, but when I change it to long, it returns every natural number as not prime.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
int check_prime(int);
 
main()
{
   int n, result;
 
   printf("Enter an integer to check whether it is prime or not.\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);
 
   result = check_prime(n);
 
   if ( result == 1 )
      printf("%d is prime.\n", n);
   else
      printf("%d is not prime.\n", n);
 
   return 0;
}
 
int check_prime(int k)
{
   if(k==1){
       return 0;
   }
   int c;
 
   for ( c = 2 ; c <= k - 1 ; c++ )
   { 
      if ( k%c == 0 )
     return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: _but when I change it to long_ You should show that code, not the working code.

Comment: So, did you change *all* uses to `long`. And, in particular, did you also change the `%d` codes?

Comment: Welcome to SO. `main()` implicit return type is a deprecated feature from previous centuries. You should get used to provide proper function signatures. For `main` they are: `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char*argv[])`

Comment: Once you use a larger type, you'll need a more efficient algorithm. `if(k<=1) return 0; if(k==2) return 1; if(k%2==0) return 0; for(c=3; c*c<=k; c+=2)` would make a start, vastly reducing the trial divisions (use the right types).

Comment: @WeatherVane `c*c<=k` overflows when `k` is a large prime near `LONG_MAX`.  `c<=k/c` is better.

Comment: @pablooooooo Post the failing code that uses `long` and the input used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My program works for integers, but when I change it to long, it returns every natural number as not prime.

"My program works for integers" but not for all `int`.
`check_prime(n)` fails when `n <= 0`.

```
Enter an integer to check whether it is prime or not.
0
0 is prime.
```

Fix with `if(k==1){` --> `if(k <= 1){`

Converting the type from `int` to `long` is insufficient.  Code must also convert the `scanf()` specifier from `"%d"` to `"ld"`.  Failure to do so results in *undefined behavior* (UB).

A common UB is that `long n; scanf("%d",&n);` results in `n` as zero.  Since `check_prime(0)` returns the wrong answer, many failed tests are expected.

Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.

---

`for ( c = 2 ; c <= k - 1 ; c++ )` is very slow for large `k` for that iterates up to O(k) times.

Use `for ( c = 2 ; c <= k/c ; c++ )`.  That iterates up to O(√k) times.

Comment: Since there's no need to check _evens_: `for ( c = 3 ; c <= k/c ; c += 2 )`??

Comment: @Fe2O3 "no need to check evens:" makes sense if there is a prior `if (k%2 == 0) return k==2;`. If not some prior even test then `for()` needs to start at 2.  IAC, it remains O(√k) . Of course there are many other optimizations too.